# TYPO3 8.X fluid pagination doesn't retain searched filters

Tags: pagination, typo3, typo3-extensions

I have a search field with a keyword textfield "key". The search form uses POST (using GET gives me an error "Page Not Found, Reason: Request parameters could not be validated (&cHash empty)")

The controller picks out the submitted keyword like so:

```
$key = $this->request->getArgument("key");
```

..it then uses this to perform a SQL search.

The results of the search are correct, however I'm using the fluid pagination, and if there is more than 1 page, I click to another page via the pagination and the "key" keyword has been lost.

How do I get the pagination to remember the "key" variable in the search field?

It seems like an obvious flaw not to provide the ability to include this data in the paginated page links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `addQueryStringMethod`configuration option to append your params to the widget:

```
<f:widget.paginate objects="{blogs}" as="paginatedBlogs" configuration="{itemsPerPage: 5, addQueryStringMethod: 'GET'}">
...
</f:widget.paginate>
```

The value for `addQuetyStringMethod` can be:

- `GET`
- `POST`
- `GET,POST` or
- `POST,GET`

Comment: You have just saved my October -  THANK YOU!
I'm surprised I couldn't find this information when I googled it

Comment: You can find it now. Glad there is a simple solution for that.